# Highlighting page in menu on custom post types

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a page called "Portfolio". I use this page to show the archive for my custom post type called "Works". I do this by displaying the portfolio page on with a custom template called "Work archive".

I would like to highlight the Portfolio page in my menu when I am on a single post of Works.

Can You help me?

Answer (score -1):

This could help you

```
function change_page_menu_classes($menu){
    global $post;
    if (get_post_type($post) == 'portfolio')
    {
        $menu = str_replace( 'current_page_parent', '', $menu ); // remove all current_page_parent classes
        $menu = str_replace( 'page-item-366', 'page-item-366 current_page_parent', $menu ); // add the current_page_parent class to the page you want
    }
    return $menu;
}
add_filter( 'wp_page_menu', 'change_page_menu_classes', 0 );
```

[Source](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/missing-current_page_parent-css-class-for-custom-post-types)

Comment: Thank you. Can You tell me which variables to change in this code?

Comment: orelse you can add a class in the menu for example for the menuitem named page1 add a class named my_custom_parent and then use it instead of page-item-366

Answer (score -1):

Hey I dunno if this is still relevant but I came across this and it worked great. I'm using the roots theme with a post type of "projects"

```
// Remove active class from menu
function remove_active_class($class) {
return ( $class == 'active' ) ? FALSE : TRUE;
}

// Add active class to menu of post type single template
function add_class_to_wp_nav_menu($classes) {

if( is_singular( 'projects' ) ) {

    $classes = array_filter( $classes, 'remove_active_class' );

    if( in_array( 'menu-projects', $classes) ) {
      $classes[] = 'active';
    }
} elseif( is_singular( 'resources' ) ) {

    $classes = array_filter( $classes, 'remove_active_class' );

    if( in_array( 'menu-resources', $classes) ) {
      $classes[] = 'active';
    }
}

return $classes;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'add_class_to_wp_nav_menu');
```

Comment: I am not currently working on this problem, but thank you for your response. I will try it out for my next project.

I still think that this issue should be solved at Wordpress's core, but until then we will have to do with hack and slash.

Answer (score -1):

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'namespace_menu_classes', 10, 2 );
function namespace_menu_classes( $classes , $item ){
if ( get_post_type() == 'attorneys' ) {
    $classes = str_replace( 'current_page_parent', '', $classes );
    if ( $item->url == '/attorneys' ) {
    // Replace "attorneys" with your code
    if(preg_match('/attorneys/', $item->url)) {
        $classes = str_replace( 'menu-item', 'menu-item current_page_parent', $classes );
    }
}
return $classes;
```

}

Altered from here: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-post-type-highlighting-current-menu-item

Comment: Hi Adam, welcome to SO and thanks for your answer. Would you mind editing your answer to explain how this solution works and why it solves the original problem? Code only answers are generally frowned upon as it makes it hard to understand the why and how. Thanks!